# PHP CLI not functioning with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, command-line-interface

I have php cli working perfectly on my local (windows) box with ZF2 (php 5.4.16).

I installed ZF2 and Zend Server onto linux, and php5-cli separately (php 5.4.22). After importing my project I try running a console script: `php public/index.php update`

This doesn't work, nor does it output anything (errors, etc) when I run it in linux. Is the problem a version error? How can I use the native php cli installed by Zend Server on my linux box (if that makes sense)?

Edit:

It looks like php stops working after this line in index.php:

`Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();`

So my php cli fails to run the zend application. How can I make sure the cli functions correctly?

Comment: no error message ? did you enable displaying error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use Zend's php installation by preprending the /path/to/Zend/php (/usr/local/Zend/bin) to $PATH.